# Improve performance for removing Intersection from nested lists and returning a list

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-3.x, arraylist

I have a function that takes two parameters (2 different nested list and the list size can be different ).

**The problem is i face issue with performance for arrays in range of millions.**

```
def function(a,b):
```

The first parameter is a nested list, eg `(a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]))`

The second parameter is also a nested list ,eg `(b = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]))`.

I am writing a function that returns another list that removes from first array the  interesction from the second parameter.

eg is

```
a  =[[3--15],[2--20],[5--10]]
b = [[3---5],[8--10]]  // [[3,4,5],[8,9,10]]
o/p is :[[2],[6,7],[11,12---20]]
```

for a simple example :

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,--20]]
b = [[3,4,5,6,7]]
op = [[1,2],[8,9,---20]]
```

I currently managed to do using the following logic:

- combine all set of 'a' into one list , lets say mg [] //mg= merge
- combine all set of 'b' into another list lets say ng [] //ng =negative
- initialize a empty list op = [] //output
- intialize another empty list z =[],this i will append to op
- create a for loop that starts with elements
  in 'mg', and checks if exists in 'ng', if the element is encountered in
  ng, then create a new z = [] ,else appends to z

Here is my code :

```
def function (a,b):
    mg = [] ## merge all data in "a"
    ng = [] ## merge all data in "b"
    for out in a: ##function to merge data in a
        for i in out:
            if i in mg:
                continue
            else:
                mg.append(i)
    for out in b: ##function to merge data in b
        for i in out:
            if i in ng:
                continue
            else:
                ng.append(i)
    ng = sorted(ng) ## sort out the value in a
    mg = sorted(mg) ## sort out the value in b
    op = []
    z =[]
    for m in mg: ## some simple logic that breaks array and creates a new one for output
        if m in ng: 
            if len(z) !=0:
                op.append(z)
                z =[]
            else:
                continue
        else:
            z.append(m)
    op.append(z)
    print("##"*20)
    print(op)
    return op
```

The code works perfect if the array size are small in the range of 100 or 1000, but if the array range are in millions (eg [`[1,2,3][5,6,7-------10,000,00]]`, the code will take a lot of time or become unresponsive in some systems with less memory. i found a  issue with the merge function that i have used which tries to append, but there might be other issues too.

I tried to google for any algrithms that might help and also tried to create a new algorithm but my brain has started to malfunction and i am out of idea.

I am looking for any solution or suggestion that could help me tackle this problem for huge array range .

Comment: Are you sublists really contiguous intervals?

Comment: No, they are not, they are not contiguous.

Comment: OK (All your examples contain only such sublists)

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two ways to do this more efficiently.

Both ways start by creating the two combined lists as you're currently doing.

The first way is to sort and de-duplicate the two lists. Now you have two sorted lists and you can do a two-way merge, picking out only those items that exist in both lists.

The other way is to create a dictionary (map) from one of the two lists. Then go through the other list item-by-item, and check to see if the item exists in the dictionary. If it does, then put it in the output array.

The first way has complexity O(n log n + m log m), where n and m are the lengths of the two lists.

The second method is O(m+n): O(m) to build the dictionary from one list, and O(n) to check all the items in the other list against the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. I am actually trying to remove the items from first list that exist in second list and create a new array. I believe the solution you purpose is for retrieving array intersection rather than removing the intersection. Many thanks for looking into it !

Comment: @SijanShrestha: The two methods I describe work for retrieving the intersections (that is, making a new array that contains just the intersection), and for making a new array that contains just the items that do not intersect. The fundamental algorithm is the same. After all, you have to *find* the common items before you can remove them.